# JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back - weblogic.transaction.RollbackException

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm getting this error instead of my custom exception when a ConstraintViolationException occurs during POST operation. This occurs when my spring boot project is deployed in the WebLogic Server.

Here is the full error

```
JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: Unexpected exception in beforeCompletion: sync=org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.RegisteredSynchronization@74a8e6a3\r\norg.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch"
```

From this post [UnexpectedRollbackException - JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456284/unexpectedrollbackexception-jta-transaction-unexpectedly-rolled-back) I know it is due to Hibernate adding it's own wrapper to my custom exception. But I couldn't find a way to prevent this. Also I tried changing the JTA transaction timeout. None of it worked.

This is how I catch the DataIntegrityViolationException

```
catch (DataIntegrityViolationException | PersistenceException ex) {
            throw new AccountValidationException(Markers.ACC_SER_ADD_2.toString(), "Account Number should be unique");
        }
```

Any workaround for this?? Thanks in advance